# MS Access 2016 Chart in Subform

Tags: ms-access, charts, subform

I'm creating a Database/ERP System for my small business with MS Access 2016. 
To resume we can assume that I have a table for the orders and a table with the customer data, like address, Person etc. The two tables are related by a customer ID - Primary Key.

Now I want to show in the Customer FORM a chart with the monthly values of orders for each customer. (x-axis: Months and y-axis: Turnover).

I can create a chart in the subform, that is linked with the customer ID and shows only the turnover for the client. The problem I have is that if the customer didn't make an order for one month, the month in the x-axis disappears. I would rather keep the month in the x-axis with no bar on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried already?

Comment: I created a subform and a chart on it. I really don't find any hint to let it work. Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Forcing data to show when there are no records is a common topic. One approach requires joining the data table to a dataset of all possible customer/date pairs. Another is a CROSSTAB query that defines the month/year headers http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#ColHead.